# jQuery positions

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem I couldn't understand, please help:

I've developed html page with images and made them draggable with jQuery UI help and I set these images position to relative and gave a left and top pixels, here is the link for the page http://ayyashsigns.com/lab/circles.html

I set:

- b1 position: style="left: 180px; top: -334px;..."
- b2 position: style="left: 233px; top: -546px;..."
- b3 position: style="left: 422px; top: -350px;..."
- mainb position: style="left: 93px; top: -330px;..."

**The problem is: when I run**

- $('span#b1').position().top I get 293
- $('span#b1').position().left I get 180
- $('span#b2').position().top I get 81
- $('span#b2').position().left I get 289
- $('span#b3').position().top I get 277
- $('span#b3').position().left I get 534
- $('span#mainb').position().top I get 297
- $('span#mainb').position().left I get 261

Why is all this difference, I need to access the images programmatically using jQuery. Can anybody explain this to me and how to fix it to give the exact location of the images.

Here is the link again: [my page circles](http://ayyashsigns.com/lab/circles.html)

Thanx in advance for any help,

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<p id="monitor">` to `<div id="monitor">` and remember to change `</p>` as well.

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#content {
    position:relative;
}

#b1 {
    top: ##px;
    left: ##px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Use position:absolute for all your circle, find the correct top and left px for it. It should start from top left of your screen for `top:0px; left: 0px;`

Now when you use `$('span#b1').position().top` it will give you the correct px.

FYI, [.position](http://api.jquery.com/position/) will return the px relative to parent, [.offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) will return the px relative to the document.

Comment: I need help with jQuery, after setting the circles to the correct position, I want some plugin or a command to make jQuery return the circles to the position they set at, for ex. if the user moved b1 from it's position to another position b1 will return slowly to it's original position.

Comment: Add revert option to your draggable. you can set the speed using revertDuration.

.draggable({ revert: true, revertDuration: 1000 });

Answer (score 2):

"The .position() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element relative to the offset parent."

If you want to get the actual CSS value you used, Try using :

```
$('span#b1').css('top');
```

Shai.

Comment: yes that would return the same value I put inside the style, but is this the exact position of the circle inside the DOM and why the height of the page increases when I add more circle (ball), I need to change the position of the images programmatically

Comment: To change the css position , just set the css property $('span#b1').css('top', '-350px'); This position, by your source code, is relative to the elements original location.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the position of the span, which is not a block element. You want to get the position of the image within the span:

```
$('span#b1 img').offset().top
```

Comment: I want to set the position of the circle using jQuery to be like in the style how to do that? I'm confused if I run the code u entered it gives me 442 and if I run $('span#b1 img').position().top I get -40

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best for you in this case, to use `position:absolute;` on each of the circles, and keep `position:relative` on `#content`. 
That way you will get correct value with `position().top` and `position().left`.